# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown on UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I was messing with UIView animations and I found the setAnimationTransition method which takes certain constants.

One of them is UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown.

I was wondering if this type of transition was possible on a UIImage view and how would I go about implementing it?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:YourView cache:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
/// ----> [YourView CodeTo Be Done];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: aha... ok - got it working - but the image just appears... how do I make it curl down? is it possible?

Comment: Although it doesn't hurt to call those class methods on `UIImageView`, it's more clear to call them on `UIView`