# Curl(Swipe) effect in UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, swipe

I am making an app having many images.I am using UIImage view. I want to add curl or swipe effects in displaying images. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Use `UIPageViewController` to do this stuff.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096742/ios-developer-sample-app-to-start/22097021#22097021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to Google these problems first, as there is a lot of information available for your topic. You can see get more information on links below:

- [iOS curl up animation to remove uiimageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331978/ios-curl-up-animation-to-remove-uiimageview)
- [Fold/curl edge of UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496084/fold-curl-edge-of-uiimageview)
- [page curl animation with transparent UIImageView (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767274/page-curl-animation-with-transparent-uiimageview-ios)
- [UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown on UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684030/uiviewanimationtransitioncurldown-on-uiimageview)
- http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/36548-changing-an-ui-imageview-with-page-curl-transition.html

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIImageView to the the Viewcontroller and add it as subViewcontroller to the UIPageViewController